# Проблема с границей сайта в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Отчего могла возникнуть ситуация, как на видео?
Сайт продолжается за футером. 
[Ссылка на видео](https://youtu.be/bDLnz3kVJVI)

```css
@import url("/css/oblacheniya.css");
@import url("/css/oblacheniya-type-select.css");
@import url("/css/product-page.css");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #B63D32;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2vh solid black;
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 1vh solid black;
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  width: 11.1vh;
  height: 11vh;
  padding-top: 0.8vh;
  padding-right: 11.5vh;
}

.logo img {
  width: 11.3vh;
  height: 11vh;
  margin: 0vh auto;
  padding-top: 0vh;
}

.main_title {
  padding-top: 0.2vh;
  margin-left: 0vh;
  padding-right: 0vh;
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0vh 0.4vh rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
  text-align: center;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.14vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -0.3vh;
  padding-right: 0vh
}

.second_subtitle {
  font-size: 2.3vh;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0.1vh 0.05vh 0.3vh rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  background-color: #666666;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  letter-spacing: -0.055vh;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -0.2vh;
}

.top_navigation-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1.5vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.top_navigation-menu li {
  width: 100%;
}

.top_navigation-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.top_navigation-menu li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.top_navigation-menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2.35vh;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.container1 ul {
  padding-bottom: 0vh;
  margin-bottom: 0vh;
}

.container1 ul li {
  padding-bottom: 0vh;
  margin-bottom: 0vh;
}

.container1 ul li>a:hover {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 114vh;
}


/*ЛЕВОЕ МЕНЮ*/


/*ЛЕВОЕ МЕНЮ*/

.spisok {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #7B2019;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*border*/
  border-top: 1.6vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 2vh solid #000;
  border-left: 1.5vh solid #000;
  border-right: 0vh solid #000;
  /*border ends*/
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.spisok li {
  width: 24vh;
  list-style-image: none;
  height: 5.5vh;
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 0.45vh;
}

#oblacheniya {}

.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.spisok ul>li:hover {
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu_hover.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: center no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok ul li>a:hover {
  text-shadow: gold 0 0 4vh;
  /* Свечение голубого цвета */
  color: white;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0vh;
}

.button.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0vh;
}

.spisok ul {
  list-style-image: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.spisok ul li a p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#ugol {
  background-image: url(/img/span_menu_black.png);
}

.text-div {
  width: 15.8vh;
  height: 3vh;
}

.letter-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 0.1vh;
}

.ryasi {
  letter-spacing: 0.2vh;
}


/*Начало SECTION*/

section {
  background: url(/img/fon.png);
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 114vh;
  /*РАМКА*/
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-top: 0vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 0vh solid black;
  /*Конец РАМКИ*/
}

.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 109.9vh;
}

.Nashi_Tseny {
  width: 100%;
  height: 106.9vh;
}

.photo-price {
  height: 100vh;
}

.text-price {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 98vh;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
  border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
  border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}

.text-price {
  font-size: 2.3vh;
  font-family: Yanone Kaffeesatz, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}

.text-price p {
  padding-left: 2vh;
}

#first_abzac {
  margin-top: -2vh;
}

.photo-price {
  height: 97vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.border-price {
  max-width: 10vh;
}

.choose_otstup {
  margin-left: 1vh;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 3vh;
  font-size: 4.7vh;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 0.5vh;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
  text-align: center;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 2.1vh;
}

.vosem_tis {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.9vh;
}


/*НАЧАЛО FOOTER*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  ;
  border-top: 1vh solid black;
  ;
  border-bottom: 2vh solid black;
  ;
}


/*КОНЕЦ FOOTER*/

#leftmenu-wrapper {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}


/*@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
h2{
  padding-right: 11%;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1999px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
h2{
  margin-left: 13.5vh;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
h2{
  padding-left: 520px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1220px) {
h2{
  padding-left: 120px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1355px) {
h2{
  padding-left: 300px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1504px) {
h2{
  padding-left: 380px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1700px) {
h2{
  padding-left: 520px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
h2{
  padding-right: 90px;
}
}
*/
```

```html
<main>

  <section>
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
        <h2>Наши цены:</h2>
        <div class="photo-price">
          <div class="text-price">
            <p id="first_abzac"><u><b>Облачения</b></u>:</p>
            <p class="choose_otstup">-иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">9000</span></strong> &nbsp; рублей с шикарными галунами</p>
            <p class="choose_otstup">-иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">10000</span>&nbsp;</strong> рублей<strong>*</strong></p>
            <p><u><b>Подрясники</b></u>:</p>
            <p><u><b>Подризники</b></u>:</p>
            <p><u><b>Рясы</b></u>:</p>
            <p><u><b>Стихари</b></u>:</p>
            <p><u><b>Скуфии</b></u>:&nbsp;от 800 рублей;</p>
            <p><u><b>Камилавки</b></u>:&nbsp;от 1700</p>
            <p><u><b>Крещальные</b></u>:</p>
            <p><u><b>Облачения для храма</b></u>:</p>
            <p><u><b>Вышитые кресты</b></u>:</p>
            <p><u><b>Кадильный уголь</b></u>:</p>
            <p>*парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами шьются по заказу</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
</main>



<footer>
  <div class="container3">
  </div>
</footer>
</div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
@media (max-width: 970px) {
  .spisok li {
    width: 22vh;
    list-style-image: none;
    height: 5.5vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: center no-repeat;
    transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .spisok ul li a p {
    padding-top: 2vh;
    margin-top: 0.42vh;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {
  .spisok li {
    width: 16.5vh;
    list-style-image: none;
    height: 5.5vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: center no-repeat;
    transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  #content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .spisok {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1325px) {
  .spisok li {
    width: 20vh;
    list-style-image: none;
    height: 5.4vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: center no-repeat;
    transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  .spisok li {
    width: 20vh;
    list-style-image: none;
    height: 6.5vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: center no-repeat;
    transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1295px) {
  .text-price {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90vh;
    height: 98vh;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
    border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
    border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
    border-image-repeat: round;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1155px) {
  .text-price {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70vh;
    height: 98vh;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
    border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
    border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
    border-image-repeat: round;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1090px) {
  .text-price {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70vh;
    height: 98vh;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
    border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
    border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
    border-image-repeat: round;
  }
  .spisok li {
    width: 16.5vh;
    list-style-image: none;
    height: 5.5vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: center no-repeat;
    transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .spisok li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.6vh;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .text-price {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60vh;
    height: 99vh;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 25vh 10vh 15vh 10vh;
    border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
    border-image-slice: 800 250 338;
    border-image-repeat: round;
  }
  .spisok li {
    width: 15.8vh;
    list-style-image: none;
    height: 5.5vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: center no-repeat;
    transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .spisok li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4vh;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  header {
    border-top: 1vh solid black;
    border-left: 1vh solid black;
    border-right: 1vh solid black;
    border-bottom: 0.8vh solid black;
  }
  section {
    border-left: 1vh solid black;
    border-top: 0vh solid black;
    border-right: 1vh solid black;
    border-bottom: 0vh solid black;
  }
  .text-price {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 2.8vh;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .spisok li {
    width: 15.8vh;
    list-style-image: none;
    height: 5.5vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(/img/span_menu.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: center no-repeat;
    transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .spisok li a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.05vh;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4vh;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}
```

Comment: а код опять случайно не прикрепился? :)

Comment: @humster_spb в этот раз по рассеянности. Готово с:

Comment: В приведённом коде проблема не воспроизводится - никакого продолжения за футером нет. Возможно, проблема в css-файлах, которые Вы импортируете (сюда они, естественно, не импортируются)

Comment: @humster_spb Вы пробовали с мобильной версии? Просто на компьютере и у меня все хорошо

Comment: @humster_spb есть файл с media-запросами, добавил в описание

Comment: Я пробую в отладчике (если Вы об этом). На реальном мобильнике это в любом случае не посмотреть.

Comment: @humster_spb, да я про что-либо подобное, а не про мобильник. Подскажите, а что за отладчик? Там можно менять ширину отображения результата кода?

Comment: я пользуюсь отладчиком в хроме (F12) - там можно не просто менять ширину вручную, но и выбирать конкретные девайсы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы.
В коде был лишний блок, который вылазил за футер.